# How did Strassen discover his matrix-multiplication algorithm?

Tags: soft-question, algorithms, intuition

Do we know how [Volker Strassen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volker_Strassen) discovered his famous [matrix-multiplication algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm)? In particular, is there a systematic way to derive the seven products used in Strassen's algorithm? How did Volker Strassen come up with them? I find the step very unintuitive.

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/199627/how-did-strassen-come-up-with-his-matrix-multiplication-method) on programmer.SE

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's a **great** answer.